# Accessing the base classes of a class in a class decorator

Tags: python

I want to disable multiple inheritance for a class, so, it could only inherit from one class.
One way to do this is through a metaclass, but I want to do it using a class decorator.

```
class NoMultipleInheritance(type):
  def __new__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
    if (len(bases)>1):
      raise Exception('multiple inheritance not allowed')
    
    return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, clsdict)
```

```
class B(metaclass=NoMultipleInheritance):
  pass
```

```
class C:
  pass
```

```
class A(B, C):
  pass
```

gives

```
Exception: multiple inheritance not allowed
```

But how do I get the base classes in a class decorator?

```
def no_multiple_inheritance(cls):
  # how do I get the base classes of a class here?
  return cls
```

```
class B:
  pass
```

```
class C:
  pass
```

```
@no_multiple_inheritance
class A(B, C):
  pass
```

Comment: Did you try `cls.__bases__`? For that matter, did you try putting `python get bases of class` into a search engine?

Comment: thanks, sorry, I was searching for the base classes in `cls.__dict__`

Comment: is there a reason, they do not mention `__bases__`, `__name__`, `__qualname__` when I do `dir(cls)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be solved like this,

```
def no_multiple_inheritance(cls):
  if(len(cls.__bases__)>1):
    raise Exception('no multiple inheritance allowed')
  return cls
```

using, `dir(type(cls))`, one gets the required list of attributes

```
def deco(cls):
  print(dir(type(cls)))
  print(cls.__flags__, cls.__name__)
  return cls
```

```
@deco
class C:
  pass
```

```
['__abstractmethods__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__basicsize__', '__call__',
 '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__dir__', '__doc__',
 '__eq__', '__flags__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__instancecheck__',
 '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__',
 '__ne__', '__new__', '__prepare__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
 '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__',
 '__text_signature__', '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro']
284161 C
```